# Retaining (zsh + prezto)'s color settings after aliasing

Tags: macos, zsh, iterm2, prezto

So I use zsh and prezto for my shell and I like the way I've configured my color settings (directories are cyan, etc.) but when I try to write:

```
    alias ls="ls -l"
```

to my .zshrc and reload another iterm2 window, the aliased command:

```
ls works as ls -l
```

but doesn't have any of the preconfigured colors on directories (they're plain white). Any ideas?

Comment: On OS X, ls shows colors if the CLICOLOR environment variable is set or if -G is passed on the command line, as in ls -G. The possible colors are set in the LSCOLORS environment variable. Check those environment variables in the tab which isn't showing color.

Answer (score 0):

Add `export CLICOLOR=1` to your .zshrc.